# Why can't I send an email from my app that host in GCP use Gmail SMTP?

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, smtp, gmail

I'm developing an mail service using golang and I put it on service at google cloud, my app can't send email when it hosted inside gcp, but I can do it in local.

I tried it before in localhost and I got success when sent the email, but when I run it on gcp, it didn't send anything, the log is clear, nothing about the error but log for success. Is there anything should I config in gcp?

This is my code for sending the email:

```golang
func (r *Request) SendEmail() (bool, error) {
    mime := "MIME-version: 1.0;\nContent-Type: text/html;
    charset = \"UTF-8\";\n\n"
    subject := "Subject: " + r.subject + "!\n"
    msg := []byte(subject + mime + "\n" + r.body)
    addr := "smtp.gmail.com:587"

    if err := smtp.SendMail(addr, auth, "no-reply@sample.com", r.to, msg); err != nil {
        return false, err
    }

    return true, nil
}
```

I expect to receive a msg from this mail service

Comment: https://godoc.org/net/smtp#SendMail

Comment: I used that, but I move to send grid package, which still uses that SMTP package under the hood I believe. Anyway, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Are you actually sending an e-mail from `no-reply@sample.com`? Well Gmail's anti-spam filters are going to catch you assuming the above code works.

`sample.com` doesn't have any TXT (i.e. for SPF) or MX records, and your GCE instance is certainly not going to be viewed favourably:

```
$ host -t txt sample.com.
sample.com has no TXT record

$ host -t mx sample.com.
sample.com has no MX record
```

If it does actually work, it may be in the spam folder, best case scenario.

If you edited the above e-mail for the code snippet, and you're actually sending from a domain you own, make sure your MX, SPF, and DMARC records are up to scratch. In particular, your SPF record must whitelist the IP of your GCE instance.

Comment: Thank you for your response, sorry for this kinda super late reply! And I didn't really use `no-reply@sample.com`, it was just an example, and I have already done as you said. But, I still can't send it. And I figured something out that there was a problem at my docker-image AND from what I read, there are some rules that GCP made for IF we want to send email from inside their services, like Compute Engine.